# How to resolve mongodb embedded document array of object for query in Graphql nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I am new to Graphql, and I am trying to build an application while I am learning it. Actually I am trying to write a resolver to resolve the query on following schema.
Please tell me how could I resolve the referenced object resides in the array of feedformula: [feeditemSchema]
How to get the corresponding record from farmintake for feeding.
I don't know how clearly I explained my problem to you but i am sure that when you see the structure of schema you will understand my problem. Please help a I am unable to find.
When I query as below it workes.

```
query{
feeds{
 _id
feedname
feedtime
feedformula{
  feeding{
    _id
    
  }
  qty
  mesunit
  description
  remarks
 }creator{
  email
 }
 }
 }
```

But when I use below query it raise an error:

```
query{
feeds{
_id
feedname
feedtime
feedformula{
  feeding{
    _id
    name
  }
  qty
  mesunit
  description
  remarks
  }creator{
  email
  }
 }
 }


   {
   "errors": [
   {
  "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field 
   Farmintake.name.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 81,
      "column": 8
    }
    ],
   "path": [
    "feeds",
    0,
    "feedformula",
    0,
    "feeding",
    "name"
   ]
  },
  {
  "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field 
  Farmintake.name.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 81,
      "column": 8
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "feeds",
    0,
    "feedformula",
    1,
    "feeding",
    "name"
  ]
  },
  {
  "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field 
  Farmintake.name.",
  "locations": [
    {
      "line": 81,
      "column": 8
    }
  ],
  "path": [
    "feeds",
    0,
    "feedformula",
    2,
    "feeding",
    "name"
  ]
  }
  ],
  "data": {
  "feeds": [
   {
    "_id": "62b417a91797e5053c2d58a3",
    "feedname": "Dana",
    "feedtime": "Evening",
    "feedformula": [
      null,
      null,
      null
    ],
    "creator": {
      "email": "auzrimfa@gmail.com"
    }
  }
 ]
 }
}
```

Following in Schema:

```
const feeditemSchema = new Schema({

feeding: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Farmintake'},
mesunit: {type: String},
qty: { type: Number },
description:{ type: String },
remarks:{ type: String }

});

const feedSchema = new Schema({
feedname:{ type: String },
feedtime:{ type: String },
feedformula:[ feeditemSchema ],
description:{ type: String },
creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}
},{ timestamps: true });

const farmintakeSchema = new Schema({
name:{type: String,required: true},
itmtype:{type: String,required: true},
madein:{type: String,required: true},
mesunit:{type: String},
usage:{type: String},
remarks:{type: String},

creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}
},{ timestamps: true}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Feed', feedSchema );
module.exports = mongoose.model('Farmintake',farmintakeSchema);
```

I tried following Resolver:

```
const transformFeed = feed =>{


return {
    ...feed._doc,
    _id: feed.id,
    feeding: farmintake.bind(this, feed.feedformula.feeding),
    creator: user.bind(this,feed.creator)
    
 };

};
const farmintake = async farmintakeId => {
try{
    const farmintake = await Farmintake.findById(farmintakeId);
   
    return {
        ...farmintake._doc,
        _id:farmintake.id
        
    };

}catch (err) {
    throw err;
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of waiting for any reply, I struggled and found the solution by myself, below is my solution and it worked for me, experts feedbacks are requested to suggest for any improvement. My Graphql query is working now as below.

```
query{
 feeds {
  id
  feedname
  feedtime
  feeditems {
    farmintakes {
      id
      name
      remarks
    }
    id
    qty
    mesunit
    description
    remarks
  }
}
}
```

Query Result as I wanted:

```
{
"data": {
  "feeds": [
    {
      "id": "62b417a91797e5053c2d58a3",
      "feedname": "Dana",
      "feedtime": "Evening",
      "feeditems": [
        {
          "farmintakes": [
            {
              "id": "62323fd1109749e4a4f49a02",
              "name": "Green Maiz Leaf (Makai Chara)",
              "remarks": "Green sliced maiz for evening feed "
            }
          ],
          "id": "62b418ad1797e5053c2d58b2",
          "qty": 6,
          "mesunit": "Kg",
          "description": "Testing Goat Feed",
          "remarks": "1st Goat Feed"
        },
        {
          "farmintakes": [
            {
              "id": "62323f06109749e4a4f499ff",
              "name": "Millet (Jawar)",
              "remarks": "Mix with morning feed of Goat"
            }
          ],
          "id": "62b4183b1797e5053c2d58ad",
          "qty": 3.5,
          "mesunit": "Kg",
          "description": "Testing Goat Feed",
          "remarks": "1st Goat Feed"
        },
        {
          "farmintakes": [
            {
              "id": "62323e49109749e4a4f499fc",
              "name": "Barley (Jau)",
              "remarks": "Mix with morning feed of Goat"
            }
          ],
          "id": "62b417d11797e5053c2d58a8",
          "qty": 2.5,
          "mesunit": "Kg",
          "description": "Testing Goat Feed",
          "remarks": "1st Goat Feed"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
}
```

After changes the Schema looking like as:

```
const feeditemSchema = new Schema({
feedId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Feed'},
farmintakeId : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Farmintake'},
mesunit: {type: String},
qty: { type: Number },
description:{ type: String },
remarks:{ type: String }

});

const feedSchema = new Schema({
feedname:{ type: String },
feedtime:{ type: String },
feeditems:[ {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Feeditem'}],
description:{ type: String },
creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}
},{ timestamps: true });

const farmintakeSchema = new Schema({
name:{type: String,required: true},
itmtype:{type: String,required: true},
madein:{type: String,required: true},
mesunit:{type: String},
usage:{type: String},
remarks:{type: String},

creator: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}
},{ timestamps: true}
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Feed', feedSchema );
module.exports = mongoose.model('Feeditem',feeditemSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Farmintake',farmintakeSchema);
```

TypeDefs:

```
type Feed {
  id: ID!
  feedname: String!
  feedtime: String!
  description: String
  feeditems:[Feeditem!]!
  
 }

 type Farmintake {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  itmtype: String
  madin: String
  mesunit: String
  usage: String
  remarks: String
 }

 type Feeditem{
  id: ID!
  mesunit: String
  qty: Float
  description: String
  remarks: String
  farmintakes:[Farmintake!]!
 }
```

Finally the Resolver:

```
Feed:{
      feeditems:(parent,args,context) => {
      const { Fid } = parent.id;
      return feeditems.filter((feeditem) => feeditem.feedid === Fid );
  
     },
   },
Feeditem:{
  farmintakes:(parent,args,context) => {
    const { Fiid } = parent.farmintakeId;
    return farmintakes.filter(( farmintake ) => farmintake.id === 
 parent.farmintakeId );
    }
  }
```